# How to create nested JSON for the multi-level menu list using PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have been trying to create a **multi-level** nested JSON using MySQL data using PHP.

I will need this JSON so I can later on use jQuery to create HTML menu.

But I'm currently struggling to create my multi-level nested JSON. I have found 100's of similar questions on Stackoverflow website and google but they all slightly different.

Basically, I have a MYSQL database that looks like this:

```
id    post_title    post_parent

1     test 1         0
2     test 2         1
3     test 3         1
4     test 4         0
5     test 5         3
6     test 6         5
7     test 7         5
```

The column `post_parent` is the column that links them together.

I've tried using the following PHP code but the JSON output is wrong.

My current PHP code:

```
$return_arr=  array();
  $sql = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_title !='Hello world!' AND post_title !='' ORDER BY post_title");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql ,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
  {

        if( !isset( $return_arr[ $row['post_parent'] ] ) ) {

            $return_arr[ $row['post_parent'] ] = array();

        }

        if( !isset( $return_arr[ $row['post_title'] ][ $row['post_title'] ] ) ) {

            $return_arr[ $row['post_parent'] ][ $row['post_title'] ] = array();

        }


  }       
  echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

The output of the above code is like this which is wrong:

```
{

    "0": {
        "test 1": [],
             "test 4": []
    },
    "1": {
        "test 2": [],
            "test 3": []
    },
    "3": {
        "test 5": []
    },
    "5": {
        "test 6": [],
            "test 7": []
    }

}
```

this is not showing a correct multi-level nested JSON data.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I will need a multi-level nested JSON like this structure:

```
   [  
 {
    "post_title":"Test 1",
    "children":[  
       {  
          "post_title":"test 3",
          "children":[  
             {  
                "post_title":"test 5",
                "children":[  
             {  
                "post_title":"test 6"
             },
              {  
                "post_title":"test 7"
             }
          ]
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          "post_title":"test 2"
       }
    ]
 }
]
```

So then I can create a multi-level menu like this:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Menu-List-Generator-jQuery-renderMenu/index2.html

Comment: So what would you expect the output to be, instead? Give us an example. It's no good saying something's wrong, if you don't define what's right.

Comment: @ADyson, yes, you are correct and sorry about that. I have edited my question.

Comment: "similar to" allows for ambiguity. Please give an example based on the same source data as you've shown. Otherwise it's very hard to make any kind of meaningful comparison.

Comment: @ADyson, edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make an array with all childs and use the post_parent as index. In the example below I called this array $array_with_elements. After that you need a separate function so you can use this recursive.

```
    <?php

$array_with_elements = array();

$sql = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_title !='Hello world!' AND post_title !='' ORDER BY post_title");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql ,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
  $array_with_elements[$row['post_parent']][] = $row;
}


function add_children($array_with_elements, $wp_level){

  $nested_array = array();
  foreach($array_with_elements[$wp_level] as $wp_post){
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->title = $wp_post['post_title'];
    $obj->id = $wp_post['ID'];
    // check if there are children for this item
    if(isset($array_with_elements[$wp_post['ID']])){
      $obj->children = add_children($array_with_elements, $wp_post['ID']); // and here we use this nested function again (and again)
    }
    $nested_array[] = $obj;
  }
  return $nested_array;
}

// starting with level 0
$return_arr = add_children($array_with_elements, 0);

// and convert this to json
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how I can use your function in my sql query?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_some_more()

Comment: Your MySQL won't change. You need to populate your array first:

$array_with_elements = array();

$sql = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_title !='Hello world!' AND post_title !='' ORDER BY post_title");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql ,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
   $array_with_elements[$row['post_parent']] = $row;
}

Comment: I get these errors: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/menu.php on line 22

Comment: Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 on line 24

Comment: Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 on line 25

Comment: and on line 22 is this: foreach($wp_posts_level as $wp_post){

Comment: and on line 24 is this: $obj->title = $wp_post['post_title'];

Comment: Now I only get this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/menu.php on line 22 AND this is on line 22: foreach($wp_posts_level as $wp_post){

Comment: You're welcome :-) I hope you flag the answer as "accepted answer" so others can find the solution for the same problem easely.

Comment: Sorry, the issue is not solved. it doesn't work unfortunately. your code breaks the page but there is no error on the page either. all I see is This page isn’t working on the page!

Comment: it seems that your if(isset($array_with_elements[$wp_post['ID']]){ part breaks the page!

Comment: Yes I noticed, I also forgot to add the $obj to the $nested_array. Hopefully it works now..

Comment: Now it prints a json but its not a nested json and its not multi-level either. it only prints a one level json.

Comment: it prints this on the page: [{
 "title": "test 1"
},{
 "title": "test 2"
}, {
 "title": "test 3"
}, {
 "title": "test 4"
} 
]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168667/discussion-between-arn-and-rooz-far).